Cycle inside my app on XCode 15 beta when I add Intents Extension
issues is:
Cycle inside NeathubIntent; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'NeathubIntent' has copy command from '/Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex' to '/Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex/NeathubIntent.appex'

Raw dependency cycle trace:
target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExtractedAppShortcutsMetadata.stringsdata ->

command: P0:target-NeathubIntent-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e028fb6d96db337eccb116a80e37ec71b45-:Release:ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ->

node: /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NeathubIntent.SwiftConstValuesFileList ->

command: P0:target-NeathubIntent-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e028fb6d96db337eccb116a80e37ec71b45-:Release:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NeathubIntent.SwiftConstValuesFileList ->

node: <target-NeathubIntent-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e028fb6d96db337eccb116a80e37ec71b45--fused-phase0-compile-sources&link-binary&copy-bundle-resources> ->

command: P0:::Gate target-NeathubIntent-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e028fb6d96db337eccb116a80e37ec71b45--fused-phase0-compile-sources&link-binary&copy-bundle-resources ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex/NeathubIntent.appex ->

command: P0:target-NeathubIntent-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e028fb6d96db337eccb116a80e37ec71b45-:Release:CpResource /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex/NeathubIntent.appex /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex ->

node: /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex/ ->

directoryTreeSignature: � ->

node: /Users/neathub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bqmqdbifjhcbrrbhlaufagauurbt/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/NeathubIntent.appex/NeathubIntent.appex

Some responses suggest that this issue is related to the Build Phase order. After I adjusted the order...
enter image description here
But problems remain.
